# Linux Search for Zeroes Column 2

Tags: linux, search, awk

I've been trying different combinations of using `grep` and `find` to first print the filename and then the instances or entire rows when the second column of these two column wind speed .csv files =="0.0".   I need to search recursively from the working directory.  I've tried these solutions with grep and find below but it does not return anything when, in fact, I know there are instances of this in some .csv files in the working directory and in subdirs.

Thank you very much - I've spent some time and I know it's something easy.

```
grep -Rx --include "*SPD-daily.csv" 0.0 .
find . -name "*SPD-daily.csv" | xargs grep -i "0.0"
```

My data looks like this:

```
01/01/1991, 3.804
01/02/1991, 2.788
01/03/1991, 4.521
01/04/1991, 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will search all `*SPD-daily.csv` files from current working directory, and will check second column of each file, if second column value is zero then it will print `FILENAME`, `line number (FNR)` and `corresponding line/record ($0)`.

```
find -name "*SPD-daily.csv" -exec awk -F, '$2==0{print FILENAME,FNR,$0}' {} \;
```

If you want stop searching in file, when you find first zero in second column, you may put `exit`

```
find -name "*SPD-daily.csv" -exec awk -F, '$2==0{print FILENAME,FNR,$0;exit}' {} \;
```

Comment: Works perfect - thank you!  It appears that I do not have to tell awk the exact value of 0.0 in the 2nd column since using just "0" works fine either way that I tried.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

save your data into sample.csv

```
awk -F, '($2==0){print $0, FILENAME, FNR}' sample.csv        
01/04/1991, 0.0 sample.csv 4
```

- use comma as delimiter `-F,`
- checks column2 equals to zeror `$2==0`
- print the whole line with filename and file records/lines number `print $0, FILENAME, FNR`

I put the same data into sample.csv and sample2.csv and run

```
 find  sample* | xargs awk -F, '($2==0){print $0, FILENAME, FNR}'
```

The output is as expected:

```
01/04/1991, 0.0 sample.csv 4
01/04/1991, 0.0 sample2.csv 4
```

In your case, combine with your `grep` and `find` commands(I didn't test your commands, assume they work) it would be:

```
grep -Rx --include "*SPD-daily.csv" 0.0 . find . -name "*SPD-daily.csv" |xargs awk -F, '($2==0){print $0, FILENAME, FNR}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility that you want to filter for values that a *close* to zero but not *exactly* `$2==0.0`, you can use absolute value and a tolerance:

```
$ echo "01/01/1991, 3.804
> 01/02/1991, 2.788
> 01/03/1991, 4.521
> 01/04/1991, 0.0
> 01/04/1991, 0.001" >file

awk -F, -v tol=1e-5 'sqrt(($2-tol)^2)<=tol {print FILENAME, $0}' file
file 01/04/1991, 0.0
file 01/04/1991, 0.001
```

If you are only filtering on *exactly* `0.0` you can do:

```
$ awk '!$2' file
01/04/1991, 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

```
awk '$NF ~ /0.0/{print $2}' file
0.0
```